# 403 forbidden error when creating custom fields

Tags: custom-fields, error

I'm getitng a 403 Forbidden error when trying to create custom fields. I can create/edit templates, create/edit channels, administer members and I'm a member of the Super Admins group.

The error occurs regardless of the field type and I'm not putting any special characters in there.

Example:
Type: Text field
Name: Strapline
Shortname: cf_productinfo_strapline

The rest of the fields are set as their defaults.

The exact error is

> You don't have permission to access /promin/index.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Could it be hosting related?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a similar problem. Could you specify: - ee version / build - installed mod, ext listing - php version

Comment: I have the same problem but I just get redirected back to the default homepage which is the holding page template.

Comment: Please post the contents of your .htaccess file. Are you using NSM htaccess generator by any chance?

Comment: Brett, can you detail what the exact issue/fix was so that those of us who are experiencing the same problem know what to tell our host? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It turns out that it was a hosting issue!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is an issue with mod_security, your host would usually need to whitelist the content or similar.